# How to use Anchors in Bitbucket across pipelines?

Tags: bitbucket

Recently we migrated to Bitbucket and started writing pipelines.

I googled and understood that 'Anchors' in pipelines are used to avoid code-redundancy in pipeline.

**Example anchor**

```
definitions: 
  steps:
    - step: &build-test
        name: Build and test
        script:
          - mvn package
        artifacts:
          - target/**
```

Is there any way that I write the 'Anchor' in a common-location and call is across **multiple pipelines**?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an anchor like the one you created and reuse it in one or more pipelines. Here is an example where the `build` and `test` operations are separated into two different anchors and used strategically in 3 different pipelines.

1. A pipeline for the `main` and any `release/**` branches always automatically builds **and** tests.
2. A pipeline for the `development` branch just builds automatically (without testing).
3. A `custom` pipeline allows you to manually trigger a build against any branch and decide whether or not to manually trigger the tests.

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
definitions:
  build: &build
    name: Build
    script:
      - mvn package
    artifacts:
      - target/**
  test: &test
    name: Test
    script:
      - mvn clean test
pipelines:
  branches:
    '{main,release/**}':
      - step: *build
      - step: *test
    development:
      - step: *build
  custom:
    build-test:
      - step: *build
      - step:
          <<: *test
          trigger: manual
```